# How to know if a cgi script is executing?

Tags: cgi, cgi-bin

I have added a cgi script in cgi-bin folder.

Now... How can I know if this cgi script is executing ?

Answer (score 0):

Have the CGI script create a file. If the file exists, then you know it has been run.

Comment: You're just interested in knowing if the script actually ran, correct (in other words... is it hooked up?)? If you just add some code that create a file when the CGI script executes and then call the CGI script from wherever it's to be called from, you would have a file created. If it doesn't work... well, then the file won't exist. Alternatively, you can have the script email you or something.